# Laravel 8 - Get value from api json response

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to get the value from 'title' in an API JSON response in Laravel 8.

```
{
    "kind": "search#companies",
    "page_number": 1,
    "items_per_page": 20,
    "total_results": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "searchresults#company",
            "links": {
                "self": "/company/13082103"
            },
            "title": "BITPIX LIMITED",
        }
    ],
    "start_index": 0
}
```

The call is setup and it works as expected but I am unsure how to get the variable.

The call will only ever return 1 response within items[] as the search is based on id.

Here is my method

```
$company = Auth::user()->companies()->first();

        $apiKey = env("COMPANIES_HOUSE");

        $query = $request->validate([
            'query' => 'required',
        ]);

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $apiKey,
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept' => '*/*'

        ])->get('https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=' . $query['query']);

        $data = json_decode($response->body());
        //dd($data);

        $provider = $company->providers()->create([
            'name' => $data['items'][0]->title
        ]);
```

which produces this error:

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` relating to the ->create line

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try $data->items instead of $data["items"]

Comment: that returns 'Attempt to read property "title" on array'

Comment: $data = (array) json_decode($json);

Comment: Can you show me what is the output of dd($data) ?

Comment: so if i chang the data variable to $data = (array) json_decode($response); 

it returns Attempt to read property "items" on array

Comment: ```array:6 [▼
  "kind" => "search#companies"
  "items_per_page" => 20
  "total_results" => 1
  "items" => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1642 ▼
      +"address_snippet": "361  Chesterfield Road, Dronfield, England, S18 1XJ"
      +"company_status": "active"
      +"date_of_creation": "2020-12-15"
      +"title": "BITPIX LIMITED"
    }
  ]
  "page_number" => 1
  "start_index" => 0
]
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hFeOWew

Comment: Try Loop with key `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 0):

you have to decode the json you have recieved then extract the data you want:

```
  $value = '{ "kind": "search#companies", "page_number": 1, "items_per_page": 20, "total_results": 1, "items": [{ "kind": "searchresults#company", "links": { "self": "/company/13082103" }, "title": "BITPIX LIMITED" }], "start_index": 0 }';
        $decodeValue = json_decode($value);
        $firstTitle = $decodeValue->items[0]->title; // first title is BITPIX LIMITED
```